# Custom link for wp_insert_post

Tags: customization

Is there any way to add a custom URL to the `wp_insert_post` function?

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['post_title'] ),
    'post_content'  => $_POST['post_content'],
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
 );
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: What do you mean by custom URL ?

Comment: If you mean `post slug`, then use `post_name` parameter.

Comment: If i put "Lorem ipsum" as name, the url will be "/lorem-ipsum". But i need to put to custom url for the post. In this case, i want the url to be "/myurl" instead of "/lorem-ipsum".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `post_name` parameter.

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['post_title'] ),
    'post_content'  => $_POST['post_content'],
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_category' => array( 8,39 ),
    'post_name'     => 'your-url'
 );
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: How can i add a condition to test if the "post_name" exist then update the post ?

Comment: @Senneville `if ( get_page_by_title( $_POST['post_title'] ) === null ) {... doesn't exists { else {...`

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you might be looking for this button:

[image]

Comment: No, the post should be created automaticaly...